React Native app crashes/closes when push message reaches
I am trying to implement Push messages in my react native app using firebase. All working good and i am able to send/push message from my .net core api to phone. But the moment message receives application crashes and also no message showing in phone. But the console shows clearly Message received
Here is my app.tsx
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { MMKV } from "react-native-mmkv";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import { Alert } from "react-native";

import { ThemeProvider } from "@/theme";
import ApplicationNavigator from "./navigators/Application";
import "./translations";

export const queryClient = new QueryClient();
export const storage = new MMKV();

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log("A new FCM message arrived!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage.notification));
    });

    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log("Message handled in the background!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ThemeProvider storage={storage}>
        <ApplicationNavigator />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

Here is my manifest file
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

I have no idea what I did wrong?
Update:
I am not using simulator and I tried with a second device and that also does the same.
Also when I remove
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

from manifest its not crashing. But nothing is showing in phone other than console message. I thought that pull down kinda notification shows when message receives
